# With Ultisnips, as soon as I type in insert mode I get "E488: Could not load library function Pyslice_AdjustIndices"

Tags: plugin-ultisnips

I have Vim 8.2 on Windows with Python 3.6 installed (in the `:version` menu I see `+python/dyn` and `+python3/dyn`). Not only am I unable to use the Ultisnips plugin, I am not able to type in Insert Mode at all, because with every keystroke I get the error `E488: Could not load library function Pyslice_AdjustIndices`.

Previously, with Python 3.9 installed I got the error `could not load library python36.dll` and the same behavior (an error after each keystroke).

This is my minimal `_vimrc` file

```
set rtp+=~\Vim\vimfiles\bundle\Vundle.vim

call vundle#begin('Vim/vimfiles/bundle')

" let Vundle manage Vundle, required
Plugin 'VundleVim/Vundle.vim'

Plugin 'sirver/ultisnips'
    let g:UltiSnipsExpandTrigger = '<tab>'
    let g:UltiSnipsJumpForwardTrigger = '<tab>'
    let g:UltiSnipsJumpBackwardTrigger = '<s-tab>'

" All of your Plugins must be added before the following line
call vundle#end()            " required

filetype plugin indent on    " required
```

In the only [instance](https://github.com/SirVer/ultisnips/issues/1185) of this issue which I have been able to find the answer was

> This error indicates that your Python installation is broken. Try `vim -u NONE`, then inside Vim try `:py3 import sys; print(sys.version)` and see if that works.

I tried it and got the error `E319: Sorry, the command is not available in this version`.

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]! I believe you need Python 3.6.1 to make this work. See [this answer](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/27515/18609).

Comment: @filbranden you are right, thank you!